# What is the basic skeleton for running jogamp's NEWT without X11?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I am trying to figure out how to use OpenGL on a Raspberry Pi without having to start X11.  I found https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=73489 which refers to jogamp's NEWT framework http://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/NEWT-Overview.html .  There are some sample apps, but most of them are quite complicated and I am having difficulty distilling them down.

I have another JOGL 2.3.2 java app that runs fine in amd64 linux X windows (have not yet tried it on the Pi).  It has methods like

```
public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();

    // Enable VSync
    gl.setSwapInterval(1);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL2.GL_FLAT);
    try {
        attachShaders(gl);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
//....
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    jf.setSize(800,800);
    jf.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    jf.getContentPane().add(new Pepper(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    jf.setVisible(true);
}
```

As you can see the `main` method is pretty standard.  It creates a `JFrame` and fills it with this class that extends `GLCanvas`.

I want to know what sort of `main` routine I should write to create one of NEWT's `GLWindow` instances that works without X11 and then use my existing class to `display` on that GLWindow.  Bonus points if the same `main` routine works with and without X11.

Comment: You should look at our examples based on NEWT, especially this one: https://gist.github.com/xranby/ccbcfcaef341f5bd1ba8 Rather contact Xerxes on our official forum as he owns a Raspberry Pi and he has a good experience of JOGL with this kind of device.

Comment: The code you reference works under X11 on amd64, but not headless on amd64, not headless on raspberry pi, and not X11 on raspberry pi.  glxgears works in X11 on pi, so I'm currently assuming something about the pi confuses jogamp.  This question needs a no-X11 solution.

Answer (score 0):

A skeleton that works in X11 on amd64 is

```
public static void main(String[] argv)
    throws InterruptedException
{
    GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2));
    caps.setBackgroundOpaque(true);
    final GLWindow glWindow = GLWindow.create(caps);

    glWindow.setSize(800,600);
    glWindow.setVisible(true);

    Pepper pepper = new Pepper();

    glWindow.addGLEventListener(pepper);

    Animator animator = new Animator(glWindow);
    animator.start();
}
```

but this does not work without X11 on amd64.

Headless on a Raspberry Pi it fails with

```
libEGL warning: DRI3: xcb_connect failed
libEGL warning: DRI2: xcb_connect failed
libEGL warning: DRI2: xcb_connect failed
Caught handled GLException: EGLGLXDrawableFactory - Could not initialize shared resources for EGLGraphicsDevice[type .egl, v0.0.0, connection decon, unitID 0, handle 0x0, owner true, NullToolkitLock[obj 0x14096e9]] on thread main-SharedResourceRunner
    [0]: jogamp.opengl.egl.EGLDrawableFactory$SharedResourceImplementation.createSharedResource(EGLDrawableFactory.java:518)
    [1]: jogamp.opengl.SharedResourceRunner.run(SharedResourceRunner.java:353)
    [2]: java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused[0] by GLException: Failed to created/initialize EGL display incl. fallback default: native 0x0, error 0x3001/0x3001 on thread main-SharedResourceRunner
    [0]: jogamp.opengl.egl.EGLDisplayUtil.eglGetDisplayAndInitialize(EGLDisplayUtil.java:297)
    [1]: jogamp.opengl.egl.EGLDisplayUtil.access$300(EGLDisplayUtil.java:58)
    [2]: jogamp.opengl.egl.EGLDisplayUtil$1.eglGetAndInitDisplay(EGLDisplayUtil.java:320)
    [3]: com.jogamp.nativewindow.egl.EGLGraphicsDevice.open(EGLGraphicsDevice.java:125)
    [4]: jogamp.opengl.egl.EGLDrawableFactory$SharedResourceImplementation.createEGLSharedResourceImpl(EGLDrawableFactory.java:532)
    [5]: jogamp.opengl.egl.EGLDrawableFactory$SharedResourceImplementation.createSharedResource(EGLDrawableFactory.java:516)
    [6]: jogamp.opengl.SharedResourceRunner.run(SharedResourceRunner.java:353)
    [7]: java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "main" com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Profile GL2 is not available on null, but: []
        at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.get(GLProfile.java:991)
        at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.get(GLProfile.java:1004)
        at NewtPepper.main(NewtPepper.java:15)
```

Under X11 on a raspberry pi it fails with

```
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Available GLVersions not set for EGLGraphicsDevice[type .egl, v1.4.0, connection decon, unitID 0, handle 0x63488be8, owner true, NullToolkitLock[obj 0x16eb2ec]]
        at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.initProfilesForDeviceCritical(GLProfile.java:1952)
        at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.initProfilesForDevice(GLProfile.java:1875)
        at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.initProfilesForDefaultDevices(GLProfile.java:1842)
        at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.access$000(GLProfile.java:80)
        at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile$1.run(GLProfile.java:230)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.initSingleton(GLProfile.java:216)
        at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.getProfileMap(GLProfile.java:2297)
        at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.get(GLProfile.java:988)
        at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.get(GLProfile.java:1004)
        at NewtPepper.main(NewtPepper.java:15)
```

Comment: probably related to pi failures: https://github.com/anholt/mesa/issues/24

Comment: Mar 2017 summary of problems on pi: http://forum.jogamp.org/Jogl-with-raspberry-pi3-td4037813.html